# Vector functions of STREAM benchmark

Tags: testing, memory, stream, benchmarking, memory-bandwidth

I am currently doing a small research project for school, where I am to test the memory performance bandwidth of a Hypervisor, compared to the virtualised machines it creates and manages.

Due to the timeframe of the project, only one of the vector functions tested by STREAM will be analysed. My thoughtprocess is to look at the results from the "Copy" function, since this is the most basic function, which performs no arithmetic, as stated at the bottom of https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html
After all, this is a memory bandwidth performance test.

I have yet though to find any google post that proves, or disproves my theory. Is there anyone here who can shine some light on this topic?

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the introduction, but the STREAM benchmark software by John McCalpin is the software being used in the research.

Answer (score 0):

STREAM Copy and other three tests are usually written in plain C without explicit vectorization. But the loops are simple and most compilers are able to optimize them to vectorized variant. The kernel line in https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html is the full code of loop, and there are three arrays: `a`, `b`, `c` of the same size; preinitialized with some floating point data. Element of vector is double (8 bytes typical).

> The table below shows how many Bytes and FLOPs are counted in each iteration of the STREAM loops.
>   The test consists of multiple repetitions of four the kernels, and the best results of (typically) 10 trials are chosen.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
name        kernel                  bytes/iter      FLOPS/iter
------------------------------------------------------------------
COPY:       a(i) = b(i)                 16              0
SCALE:      a(i) = q*b(i)               16              1
SUM:        a(i) = b(i) + c(i)          24              1
TRIAD:      a(i) = b(i) + q*c(i)        24              2
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

More recent variants of the test are NERSC: http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/cori/nersc-8-procurement/trinity-nersc-8-rfp/nersc-8-trinity-benchmarks/stream/ and HPCC: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/hpcc/ both based on http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/